# how can i use arrayList to store user input of customer details?

Tags: java, input

1. ```
   try {
   Customer cst[] = {new Customer(), new Customer(),new Customer(),new Customer()};
   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt"));
   for (Customer a : cst) {
       bw.write(a+ " ");
           for (int i=0;i<cst.length;i++){
                System.out.println("Enter Customer Name : ");
                   cst[i] = new Customer();
                   cst[i].name = cst.nextLine();
                   cst[i].custID = 100 + (i+1);
                   System.out.println("Customer ID Generated is:"+cst[i].custID);

                }        
                   }
                  bw.close();
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   System.out.println("error: file not created");
               }  
       try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
                    String s = "";
                    String msg = "";
                    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                       msg += s + " \n";

                   }
                    br.close();
                    System.out.println(msg);

               } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error: %s\n");
               }

               InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            }
   ```

   > Okay.  So I think the question here is "How do I rewrite this code to use ArrayList instead of a static array?" but as I am not in fact the person who wants to know I will leave it to them to confirm or deny.

Comment: Collect the user input, prepare your object, add() to your array or collection that holds the Customer objects.

Answer (score 0):

You use `s = br.readLine()` but store them without creating a new line. Instead of `bw.write(a+ " ");` try `bw.write(a + "\n");`